# Apple and Windows require pre-compiled libs at:

Tags: python, versions, windows

I'm trying to build Blender 2.71(?) as a Python module on Windows 7 with vs 2013 express and cmake. I've followed [these](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/msvc/CMake) instructions.

I've set the JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR and JPEG_LIBRARY entries to .../lib/win64_vc12/jpeg/include and .../lib/win64_vc12/jpeg/lib/jpeg.lib respectively and done this also for the other libraries like TIFF, OpenImageIO etc.

When I first changed these and clicked Configure I got messages like Found JPEG:...
After that the output is always this:

```
64 bit compiler detected.
Visual C++ 2013 detected.
Boost version: 1.55.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  date_time
  filesystem
  thread
  regex
  system
  locale
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1952 (message):
  Apple and Windows require pre-compiled libs at:
  'C:/00/blender/../lib/win64_vc12'


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/00/blender_build_python/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I have 3 main suspicions for why this might be but I don't know what to do about it:

1) Boost_DIR always gets set to Boost_DIR-NOTFOUND, even if I manually changed it. However, [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=69615) and other sources seem to indicate it shouldn't be a problem.

2) I'm not sure what to set the freetype entries to. I have FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_freetype2 set to C:/00/blender/lib/win64_vc12/freetype/include and FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIR_ft2build set to C:/00/blender/lib/win64_vc12/freetype/include/freetype2 and I got the message "Found Freetype..." but those names seem pretty weird and I don't know if it's correct.

3) There is a setting for PNG_LIBRARY_DEBUG, but there's only the libpng.dll. Setting that as the value doesn't change anything.

So, am I missing something? Is this a known issue and is there a workaround? Should using another compiler with cmake work, even if this doesn't work? Or is there maybe a zipped folder somewhere I can download, that I can just extract into my python folder so I can import it?

edit: I also tried it with the vs 2010 compiler and the win64 precompiled libraries with the same result.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about compiling blender. See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/399/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause for this problem myself: In the guide, it seems to me as if the lib folder is supposed to be inside the blender source folder (it doesn't say to leave the blender folder before running the svn command and at other places it refers to C:/BlenderDEV/lib/...)

Moving the lib folder into the same folder that the blender source folder is in gets rid of the error message. When the Cache is deleted cmake also finds all of the library locations on its own.

I always interpreted the C:/00/blender/../lib/win64_vc12 as being .../blender/none_or_more_subfolders/lib/win64_vc12, though I should have known better. :p

edit: just to be clear, I only found the answer after I had already asked the question.